# "this" is undefined in vue.js using composite API, typescript and <script setup> tring to use a custom plugin

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I'm new to vue.js and I'm trying to use a axios plugin in a basic app.
I'v followed this example:https://blog.logrocket.com/how-use-axios-vue-js/
But the reference to "this" doesn't work.
Here's were I'm stuck:

```
<script setup lang="ts">

import { reactive, onMounted } from 'vue';
import type { AxiosInstance } from 'axios'


declare module 'vue' {
     interface ComponentCustomProperties {
        $axios: AxiosInstance
        
    }
}

type Forecasts = {
    date: string
}[];

interface Data {
    loading: boolean,
    post: null | Forecasts
};

const result: Data = reactive({ loading: false, post: null })



onMounted(async () => {
await this.$axios <<<<<<<========= this is undefined
    .get('weather', { withCredentials: true })
    .then(response => {
        result.post = response.data;

    })

})

</script>
```

I've found a lot of articles but none use the combination of "script setup" composite API and typescript.

Comment: You have imported it as `axios` but accessing it as `$axios`.

Comment: Oups, forgot to remove the import statement I was using before making the plugin. I've removed it from the code. I must use $axios from the plugin.